# subtract values where column has specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table

```
| account | date       | client_ID | value |
|---------|------------|-----------|------|
| A       | 31/01/2023 | 1         | 10   |
| B       | 31/01/2023 | 1         | 2    |
| C       | 31/01/2023 | 1         | 50   |
| A       | 28/02/2023 | 1         | 15   |
| B       | 28/02/2023 | 1         | 11   |
| C       | 28/02/2023 | 1         | 50   |
| A       | 31/01/2023 | 2         | 7    |
| B       | 31/01/2023 | 2         | 10   |
```

And I want to substract for each date and client_id the value from account A by the value from account B. So, on 31/01/2023 client_id 1 will be 10-2=8, and client_id 2 will be 7-10=-3. For 28/02/2023 there is only data for client_id 1 and the result should be 15-11=4.

So, the expected output has 3 columns: date, client_id, and the difference calculated above.

It is possible that for a certain date or client_ID there is no A or B account so the code should be able to handle that as well.

How should I approach this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use an OUTER JOIN to merge the two sub-tables, then do the subtraction.

Comment: How should it handle the cases where there's no A or B? Use `0` as the missing value?

Answer (score 1):

You can `merge` both account A and B to compute the difference:

```
dfA = df[df['account'].eq('A')]  # extract account A
dfB = df[df['account'].eq('B')]  # extract account B

out = (dfA.merge(dfB, on=['date', 'client_ID'], how='outer')
          .fillna(0).drop(columns=['account_x', 'account_y'])
          .assign(result=lambda x: x.pop('value_x') - x.pop('value_y')))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
         date  client_ID  result
0  31/01/2023          1       8
1  28/02/2023          1       4
2  31/01/2023          2      -3
```

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of index alignment:

```
tmp = df.set_index(['account', 'date', 'client_ID'])

out = (tmp.loc['A'].sub(tmp.loc['B'])
       .reset_index()
       )

# or
out = (tmp.loc['A'] - tmp.loc['B']).reset_index()
```

*This enables you to perform more complex operations very easily (e.g, `(A-B)/C`).*

Output:

```
         date  client_ID  value
0  31/01/2023          1      8
1  28/02/2023          1      4
2  31/01/2023          2     -3
```